# prevent htaccess to change &curren into symbol

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

For some reasong htaccess redirect keeps changes an url with paramenters like:

`http://www.domain.om/product-name.html?language=en&currency=EUR`
to
`http://www.domain.om/product-name.html?language=en¤cy=EUR`

And I cant seem to prevent it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (c|m|p|pm)-([0-9_]+)(.html|html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ custom.php?type=html&q=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]
```

I changed the rewriterule flags  but nothing seems to help. I hope somsone can point me in the right direction or has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `QSA` flag, which preserves the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (c|m|p|pm)-([0-9_]+)(.html|html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ custom.php?type=html&q=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

What you're seeing is likely caused by the `NE` flag and other rules in your htaccess file.